# Android out of memory bitmap

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

i've problem with my app:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1136368 byte allocation with 127432 free bytes
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:636)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:366)
        at com.scoutapp.lite.ImageLoader.DisplayImage(ImageLoader.java:40)
        at com.scoutapp.lite.CustomArrayAdapter.getView(CustomArrayAdapter.java:49)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2242)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5148)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4259)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

basically i have an activity where there is a list with some image. They load correctly but when i scroll down i have a force close with this error. Here i post my two class:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private final String[] img;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

String t;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values,String[]img) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_spec, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.img=img;
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getContext().getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];
//        System.out.println(t);
    //Log.d(t,img[position]);
    if(img==null){

    }else{

    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(img[position],"drawable", context.getPackageName());
   // int drawableId = Integer.parseInt(img[position]);
        Bitmap bm;
      //  bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath),100, 100, true);
        //mPicture = new ImageView(context);
        //mPicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resourceId, imageView);
    //imageView.setImageResource(resourceId);

            //img.recycle();
            //img = null;

    }
   /* if (s.equals("Lupetti")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lupetti1);
    } else if (s.equals("Reparto")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.reparto1);
    } else if (s.equals("Clan")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.clan1);
    }
*/
    return rowView;
}
}
```

and:

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_stub;
public void DisplayImage(int url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, "url");
    //Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(url!=0)
        imageView.setImageResource(url);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto("url", imageView);
       imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

}
```

Any idea how can i resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many problems with bitmaps in android but first of all your adapter implementation is really bad, you don't re-use list rows and I'm sure it's pretty laggy and this might be source of your problems.

What you need to do first is to read about convertView pattern, use it and then tell us if the problem still occurs.

**UPDATE:**

First of wall you don't need to get LayoutInflater every time `getView()` is called, you can set it in adapters constructor and then reuse it.

Next listView has a mechanism to create only number of rows which are visible on the screen, when one row gets of the screen then it's reused. What you need to do is to check if you have to create a new row from scratch or reuse existing one and fill it with new data.

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    // Variable declarations
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values,String[]img) {
        // your code
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         // convertView is null when new row is needed
         View rowView = convertView;

         if(rowView == null) {
             // new row is needed to inflate new row
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
         }


         TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
         textView.setText(values[position]);

         // rest of your code
         return rowView;
     }
 }
```

Of course you can do some further optimalization using Holder patter.

Try to implement all of this and then tell us if you still have problem with OutOfMemory error

Comment: what in particular? There are a lot of code in the web... Can you  suggest me something?

Comment: YOU SAVED MY DAY! thanks a lot! its a little bit laggy yet but now it doesn't crash! Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't stop with that, use holder view and read a lot and your app wont be laggy at all, and I have a question why do you pass two different arrays instead of one array of object which will contain both values and image data?

Comment: Only for simplicity. I'm not so good with that...  and this code is the proof. Now i will search for optimize the code more and resolve the laggy scroll

Comment: this is not simplicity... if your adapter will exntend ArrayAdapter<YourObject> and you will pass it to super constructor then you can access your data by adapters `getItem()` method which will return YourObject at given position.

Comment: in other words i need to:
1)change the extends ArrayAdapter<String> in extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
2) remove this two lines : private final String[] values;
    private final String[] img; 
and sobstitute with only one, the constructor with the same and call this with the method getItem?

Comment: You need to pass ArrayList<YourObject> in your adapter class, and then in `super()` pass it instead of your array, then you will have access to your full data, now with code you have `getitem()` should return your values array item

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read some at Androids Developer page, specially here: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Read all 5 lessons and rewrite your code again. If it still don't work we will be happy to see what you've done wrong with the tutorial material.